# Regular expression to parse Final-Recipient email header

Tags: php, regex

I have to get any text between:

> Final-Recipient: RFC822; !HERE! Action

I need **!HERE!** from this example. There could be any string.

I tried something like:

```
$Pattern = '/Final-Recipient: RFC822; (.*) Action/';
```

But it doesn't work.

**upd**

Here is the string I'm trying to parse: http://dpaste.com/187638/

Comment: How do you define the end of !HERE!? Is it always in exclamation marks?

Comment: After need text follows ' Action/'

Comment: The slash is not in your original post

Comment: @Ockonal my bad on the string. thanks! deleted answer.

Comment: Hm, the slash is needed by regular expressions. The original text is: Final-Recipient: RFC822; ... Action

Comment: Can the string contain "Action"?

Comment: Why doesn't that work? The string you linked to works fine with that code. Can you show the script you're using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pattern works fine for me:

```
$i = 'This is a MIME-encapsulated message --o3ONXoEH01blah3:35:33 +0400 (MSD) Final-Recipient: RFC822; !HERE! Action: failed Status: 4.4.7 Lblahru> From: *
@*.ru';    
$pattern = '/Final-Recipient: RFC822; (.*) Action/';
$matches = Array();
preg_match($pattern, $i, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Final-Recipient: RFC822; !HERE! Action
    [1] => !HERE!
)
```

Note also that your pattern will fail if the "any text" contains new lines. Use the [DOTALL modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) `/.../s` to allow the dot to also match new lines. Also note that if the text " Action" appears elsewhere in the message it will cause your regular expression to fail. Matching dot is dangerous. Try to find a more specific pattern if possible.

Comment: To tell the truth, there could be only email addresses. Any newlines.

Answer (score 3):

Since you said "any string" which may contain spaces, the closest approximate would be

```
$Pattern = '/Final-Recipient: RFC822; (.*?) Action/s';
#                                        ^         ^
# lazy match instead of greedy match ----'         |
#                    allow . to match newline -----'
```

Of course it won't match `"Final-Recipient: RFC822; Action Action"`.

Comment: Look update, please. This regexp does'nt work for given text.

Answer (score 1):

```
$Pattern = '/Final-Recipient:[^;]+[;|<|\s]+([^\s|^<|^>]+)/i';
```

The following expression turned out to be the best for my problems, because sometimes there are lines of the following kind:

```
Final-Recipient: LOCAL;<example@rambler.ru>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am going to suggest a method that does not use them, which requires extra busywork.

```
<?php
$message = 'This is a MIME-encapsulated message --o3ONXoEH016763.1272152184/zvm19.host.ru The original message was received at Fri, 23 Apr 2010 03:35:33 +0400 (MSD) from roller@localhost ----- The following addresses had permanent fatal errors ----- "Flucker" ----- Transcript of session follows ----- 451 grl.unibel.by: Name server timeout Message could not be delivered for 2 days Message will be deleted from queue --o3ONXoEH016763.1272152184/*.host.ru Content-Type: message/delivery-status Reporting-MTA: dns; zvm19.host.ru Arrival-Date: Fri, 23 Apr 2010 03:35:33 +0400 (MSD) Final-Recipient: RFC822; !HERE! Action: failed Status: 4.4.7 Last-Attempt-Date: Sun, 25 Apr 2010 03:36:24 +0400 (MSD) --o3ONXoEH016763.1272152184/zvm19.host.ru Content-Type: message/rfc822 Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit Return-Path: Received: (from *@localhost) by *.host.ru (8.13.8/Zenon/Postman) id o3MNZX5h059932; Fri, 23 Apr 2010 03:35:33 +0400 (MSD) (envelope-from *@roller.ru) Date: Fri, 23 Apr 2010 03:35:33 +0400 (MSD) Message-Id: <201004222335.o3MNZX5h059932@*.host.ru> From: *
@*.ru';
$left_delimiter = 'Final-Recipient: RFC822; ';
$right_delimiter = ' Action';
$left_delimiter_pos = strrpos($message, $left_delimiter);
$right_delimiter_pos = strpos($message, $right_delimiter);
$desired_message_fragment = '';
if ($left_delimiter_pos !== false && $right_delimiter_pos !== false) {
    $fragment_start = $left_delimiter_pos + strlen($left_delimiter);
    $fragment_length = $right_delimiter_pos - $fragment_start;
    $desired_message_fragment = substr(
        $message, $fragment_start, $fragment_length
    );
}
var_dump($desired_message_fragment);
```

Answer (score 0):

a bit late....

but has been asked in terms of how to solve a problem that is not quite his requirements Op perhaps has joined multiple lines onto one line?(imho).

This might help others....

I'm assuming that op is trying to parse the Final-Recipient header field of a delivery status notification.

The spec for the Final-Recipient field can be seen here: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3464#page-15

If the problem is broken down, op can pull the final recipient field as a single field (Final recipient followed by a char/blank line on the next line.

e.g.

```
Original-recipient: rfc822;some-email-that-does-not-exist@gmail.com
Final-recipient: rfc822;some-email-that-does-not-exist@gmail.com
Action: failed
Status: 5.1.1 (Remote SMTP server has rejected address)
```

Final recipient is followed by the start of the next field, Action which has A on the next line. ie not followed by a space or blank line.

then all he has to do is split the line on ; and take the second part

ie

```
String[] twoparts = "Final-recipient: rfc822;some-email-that-does-not-exist@gmail.com".split(";",2) // 2 here means (2-1) = 1 match
String email = twoparts[1]
```